# need help on reset/clear jcombobox values

Tags: java, swing, reset, jcombobox

im using below coding to add values to a jcombobox using another jcombobox and i need to add the values to the jcombobox2 according to the one get selected in the jcombobox1 without appending values so can someone tell me a way to reset or clear the combo-box values when another option selected? 
below is my coding and i'm new to java and netbeans so if someone can help i'll be grateful :)

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database1", "root", "senura123");
    Statement stat = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String val=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String check; String col;
    if ("Vehicles".equals(val)){
        check = "select reg_no from vehicle;";
        col="reg_no";
    }
    else if ("Travel Guides".equals(val)){
        check = "select username from travelguide;";
        col="username";
    }
    else{
        check = "select username from transportofficer";
        col="username";
    }                   
    ResultSet rslt = stat.executeQuery(check);
    while (rslt.next()) {
        jComboBox2.addItem(rslt.getString(col));                               
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [`DefaultComboBoxModel.removeAllElements()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#removeAllElements())

> Empties the list.

Answer (score 1):

Set a *new* model into your combobox:

```
final List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

while (rslt.next()) {
  values.add(rslt.getString(col));
}

jComboBox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(values.toArray()));
```

See [DefaultComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html).

---

As a further comment, however, depending on how much latency is involved in your query, you may like to split this work up into EDT and background thread parts using [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply! i've set a new model like you showed, in the combobox1 itemstatechanged event and it worked! :) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually it happens because you have an event associated JComboBox. It is solved if you have control item in the JComboBox to act, for example:

```
jComboBoxExample.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
     do_run ();
   }
});



public void do_run() {
  int n=jComboBoxPerfilDocumentos.getItemCount(); <--THIS IS THE SOLUTION
  if (n> 0) { 
    String x = jComboBoxPerfilDocumentos.getSelectedItem (). ToString ();
  }
}
```